# Is there a way to disable a view helper inside the controller/action?

Tags: zend-framework, view-helpers

I have my view helpers in the layout like:

```
$this->viewSearchForm();
```

that is ok, in all the pages is show it, but what if a have two or tree page where i don't want to show that view helper? is this possible?

something like in an action:

```
$this->view->disable('viewSearchForm');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a flag to your view from your controller (init method or specific action).

In your layout you can have something like

```
if (!isset($this->disableSearchForm)) {
    echo $this->view->viewSearchForm();
}
```

and from your controller send the following

```
$this->view->disableSearchForm = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't "disable" a view helper. If the helpers you have are in a specific folder, a workaround could be to remove that folder from the helper path using `setHelperPath()`, but the default view helpers path is never overwritten. See the [Zend_View_Helper documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.paths) for details.

Hope that helps,